# How to run with hemorrhoids?

Tags: running, injury, health

During last autumn I had a pain caused by hemorrhoids.

I got meds from a doctor and changed my lifestyle a bit. I changed my diet and started to run. I actually found running awesome sport, as I can do it both alone and with other people, both in park nearby and new places. I lost 10 kg, started to feel happier (endorfines!) and less sleepy.

I had a half year period with no pain at all and suddently it came back. It happened to me after more intensive training (a track with many ascents), followed by quite intensive walk in the mountains. I've also drunk much coffee during the walk which presumably increased blood pressure.

I'm currently following my doctor advice to rest from intensive sport, to let my hemorrhoids turn back from 3rd degree. I'm taking meds.

But then I would like to come back to running and wonder how can I avoid similar problems in the future. I've read hemorrhoids are quite common issue for runners but despite this issue they still are actively running.

What would you advice me? Are there any exercises to make me more resistent to such issues? Will exercises for core stability help?

So far, I've been doing the following:

- removed coffee and tea completely from my diet to avoid high blood pressure
- limited spicy stuff from my diet like pepper or onion
- removed beer and any other alcohol almost completely
- stopped reading books in a toilet :-)
- high fiber diet (plums, peaches, etc.) and supplements with fiber
- drink more water and linseed
- taking sitz baths with camomile and oak bark

Answer (score 3):

A few thoughts...

1. Dehydration is a common trigger, and it's easy for that to happen if you work out for long periods.
2. Milk of magnesia is your friend. It works by changing the osmotic balance of your intestines and keeping more water in the intestinal tract, making things softer. Great when you are having issues.
3. I cycled regularly with hemmorhoids and not many issues. I think it would be harder to keep them reduced with running because of the impact. If cycling is an option, I recommend it. I did it even with 3rd grade ones. Exercise is good at getting the blood flowing and that helps. If you can't run or cycle, walking is pretty good as well.
4. Banding is mostly painless if done right and has a pretty good track record. I don't think they work well with 3rd grade, but if they reduce back to 2nd you are a good candidate. You can help this along with direct pressure and trying to (gently) push them back inside.
5. If you have access to a hot tub, that really helps.

Comment: +1 Great. Milk of magnesia seems not be available in my country, so I'm looking for an alternative. I understand this is not a suplement but a medicine that one can take only in case of constipation, right?

Comment: By banding you mean "rubber band ligation", a short procedure made by a doctor?